# Find the smallest postive integer $n$ such $H(n)<H(n+1)$

Tags: contest-math

Let $$H(x)=\dfrac{\sin{\frac{\pi}{6}x}}{x}$$

Find the smallest postive ineteger $n$ such
$$H(n)<H(n+1)$$

My approach is the following:
I use [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%28pi%2F6*x%29%2Fx) found $n=9?$

Now  I don't know how to prove it..
[image]

Comment: What is $f$? $f=H$ ?

Comment: Write out the first few values of $\sin\frac\pi6x$.

Comment: Now that you have edited it, columbus8's comment finishes it. $n=9$ doesn't need *that many* trial verifications.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
0&\to\frac\pi6=&\sqrt{{\pi^2705600}/{25401600}}\\
1&\to\frac12=&\sqrt{{4762800}/{25401600}}\\
2&\to\frac{\sqrt3}4=&\sqrt{{6350400}/{25401600}}\\
3&\to\frac13=&\sqrt{{2822400}/{25401600}}\\
4&\to\frac{\sqrt3}8=&\sqrt{{1190700}/{25401600}}\\
5&\to\frac1{10}=&\sqrt{{254016}/{25401600}}\\
6&\to0=&\sqrt{0/{25401600}}\\
7&\to-\frac1{14}=&-\sqrt{{129600}/{25401600}}\\
8&\to-\frac{\sqrt3}{16}=&-\sqrt{{297675}/{25401600}}\\
9&\to-\frac19=&-\sqrt{\color{green}{313600}/{25401600}}\\
10&\to-\frac{\sqrt3}{20}=&-\sqrt{{190512}/{25401600}}\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Proofreading required.